# inApp purchase in an iPad/iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, xcode4

I have an App that allows for an inApp purchase.  Works great, except if a user purchases it from the App Store (not from within my app), and then goes into my App, it does not know it was purchased.  How can I tell if it was purchased already?

My App is live but I have this newly discovered bug so hopefully someone can answer this for me soon!! -:)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `restoreCompletedTransactions` of the SKPaymentQueue Class to lookup which items the user already purchased and take further actions to deliver the items/functions to your user.
The documentation is your friend ;-)  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008257